# TypeScript thinks that useState returns [T | undefined, ...], why?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

If I declare a type as the following

```js
type UseBoolean = ReturnType<typeof React.useState<boolean>>;
```

`UseBoolean` is inferred to be

```js
[boolean | undefined, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean | undefined>>]
```

But when I look at the source for `React.useState`,

```js
function React.useState<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<S>>]
```

this would make me think `UseBoolean` should be

```js
[boolean, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>]
```

so why isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But when I look at the source for `React.useState`...

There's a second overload below it, which is being picked up by your type (but we can fix that, keep reading):

> ```typescript
> function useState<S = undefined>(): [S | undefined, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S | undefined>>];
> ```

It's there to allow for the case where the user doesn't supply an initial value for the state member. Example ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocgeirgHVgYALOAOwjmFceBQBs4AN34BXJAC5yaCKwDO8JAA8AjHAC8iYjAB0I2UgDKMFDCQAeAEYQIfVKwB8ACgCUFGnA9wAegH5K7hmY4FFZObhheAWE+MUlpOQVFACZ1TXQdPUNjU0trWxCnGCgxV2paT18gA)):

```typescript
import React from "react";

// With no initial value:
const ex1 = React.useState<boolean>();
//    ^? const ex1: [boolean | undefined, React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean | undefined>>]

// With an initial value:
const ex2 = React.useState<boolean>(true);
//    ^? const ex2: [boolean, React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>]
```

I can't think of a way to grab just the first overload, but we can remove the `undefined` with a mapped type:

```typescript
type NoUndefinedState<T> =
    T extends [infer S | undefined, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<infer S | undefined>>]
    ? [S, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<S>>]
    : never;
```

Then:

```typescript
type UseBoolean = NoUndefinedState<ReturnType<typeof React.useState<boolean>>>;
//   ^? type UseBoolean = [boolean, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>]

type UseString = NoUndefinedState<ReturnType<typeof React.useState<string>>>;
//   ^? type UseString = [string, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>]
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgDkIBVAOwBMlNhWl2BlGChhIAPABUAfHAC85OArji4SAB4iOAZzgBtHpiRQ4-OAB84AVw5cefADSJiMAHQARYJrDC0AC1HJ0F34kGEFhJABBDGAIVlF9Q2MzS2tuXnZJSQBdeUUAfl1+BwCMNw8vGF9-J2dg0KERKJgYuP5MnMU4AC44XgA3QwoqWnpmTSQAIQgIABtUVllGFlTbAQaxZBgLKFZxEdEaOghMR0DnC3GwkVEAI2m5lFZMyQoAelfFAD08ykPRy5gUB4AHNFkw2Jw0nwrhsQttdvs-sdTqULkgYaJNICQc83h8FN8gA)

If we want to, we can make it simpler to create these `UseXYZ` types:

```typescript
type UseStateTuple<T> = NoUndefinedState<ReturnType<typeof React.useState<T>>>;
```

Then using it is:

```typescript
type UseBoolean = UseStateTuple<boolean>;
//   ^? type UseBoolean = [boolean, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>]

type UseString = UseStateTuple<string>;
//   ^? type UseString = [string, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>]
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgDkIBVAOwBMlNhWl2BlGChhIAPABUAfHAC85OArji4SAB4iOAZzgBtHpiRQ4-OAB84AVw5cefADSJiMAHQARYJrDC0AC1HJ0F34kGEFhJABBDGAIVlF9Q2MzS2tuXnZJSQBdeUUAfl1+BwCMNw8vGF9-J2dg0KERKJgYuP5MnMU4AC44XgA3QwoqWnpmTSQwkXELMAAbMSlZRhZU2wEGsWQYCyhWcRHRGjoITEdA5wtxyYXMySGj0fGAIQgIeZRWJbGJjem5sQARq93qw7uQAPTgxQAPTylAecG+gigPAA5l8rr8ZvNRJoYCjWKiwZCYXkgA)

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `useState` hook in TypeScript, you can specify the type of the state being managed by the hook. In your case, the type is defined as UseBoolean. However, since no code is shown to demonstrate the usage of the hook, it is assumed that you did not provide an initial value. As a result, the following code:

`const [bool, setBool] = useState<boolean>();`

will result in a type of `boolean | undefined`.

If I am incorrect, kindly furnish additional examples to illustrate the usage of the useState hook.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that `UseBoolean` is not inferred as `[boolean, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>]` is because of the way that TypeScript infers the type of generic functions.

When you call `React.useState<boolean>` with a boolean argument, TypeScript correctly infers the type of the returned tuple as `[boolean, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>]`.

However, when you use `ReturnType<typeof React.useState<boolean>>` to extract the return type of the useState function, TypeScript loses the information about the type argument boolean that was passed to useState. As a result, the type that is inferred for UseBoolean is the raw return type of useState, which includes the type parameter S.

Since the type parameter S can be any type, TypeScript conservatively infers it as boolean | undefined, which means that the returned tuple `[boolean | undefined, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean | undefined>>]` includes both boolean and undefined as possible values.